# Mechanize attribute error no attribute "abc"

Tags: python-3.x, mechanize

I just pip installed mechanize but I keep getting an error when executing the file

This is the error

```
    br = mechanize.Browser()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 161, in __init__
    UserAgentBase.__init__(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_useragent.py", line 103, in __init__
    ua_handlers[scheme] = klass()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 695, in __init__
    assert is_mapping(proxies), "proxies must be a mapping"
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mechanize\polyglot.py", line 120, in is_mapping
    return isinstance(x, collections.abc.Mapping)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'abc'
```

The code is just this

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
```

Comment: It's an old library and nobody's updated it in years. I recommend switching to requests.

Comment: Last time I checked requests can barely log into any website lol.